# Running Cable Underground in PVC Conduit - Do I bond the PVC segments before pulling the wire through?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, pvc, underground

I have the PVC segments with the flanges at one end, and a relatively short (under 50ft) run, but its very bendy at the ends.

My initial thought was to pull the cable through the pieces one by one, get them in positions, mark a 45deg twist, uncouple them, put on the binding material and put them back on and twist them into position.

But I have read conflicting information on this method being up to code.

Is there a simple, definitive answer to this?

Comment: By "very bendy" do you mean more than four 90-degree bends?

Comment: 2 sets of 4 90deg bends (one set at the house, one set at the garage)

Comment: Why are they all bends? Can't you get a conduit body somewhere in there?

Comment: old house with really weird layout and additions meaning the waire form the box/basement has to come out 6 feet from where it needs to end up to have a stright shot to the lamppost (1st box).

Then it has to come out of that box turn 90 a few feet away to get under the stone path (making mud water boring that little tunnel was fun) but because everything sucks the driveway pavement and the fence with concrete posts are all in the way so I have to come up to the garage in a weird spot.

Comment: Oh, you're gonna want a pro to pull that.  Unless you made the pipes extra big.

Comment: Code maximum is four 90 degree bends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a simple, definitive answer to this?

Yes

It may seem more convenient to install the wire as you go in a very few cases but the National Electrical Code prohibits it and is quite clear.

From the 2017 NEC:

> **300.18 Raceway Installations.**
>
> (A) Complete Runs. Raceways, other than busways or exposed raceways having hinged or removable covers, shall be installed complete between outlet, junction, or splicing points prior to the installation of conductors.

Most electricians would normally just use a fishtape to pull the wire in after installation. It really is a whole lot easier than trying to stuff the conduit over the wire and then glue it together.

An alternative is a pull string vacuumed into the conduit with a piece of plastic baggy on the end. (Make sure you pull slow and easy to avoid the string cutting through the 90ºs.)

Good luck!

Comment: It was a pita since we probably dont have the best tools, but we put it together with fishing wire inside the whole thing, put on the adhesive, then pulled the cable through the lot. TY!

Answer (score 2):

Best to run the wire though the conduit after it's glued together.  See attached link for best results using a pull string: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOG-E8NQipY

Believe me, this technique is foolproof! I recommend that you purchase a hand spool at Home Depot and hold at other end of pipe to feed through pipe to eliminate possible tangling of string spread out on ground

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-3-64-in-x-500-ft-Yellow-Nylon-Mason-Twine-14148/202819400